# Got an electric shock from a USB type C cable plugged to a laptop, how can I find the faulty thing?

Tags: usb, usb-c

I was about to charge my phone with the USB type C cable that was plugged to my laptop.
When I grabbed the cable I got a light electric shock (I think I touched the plastic case that covers the metal but I'm not sure).
When that happened, I wasn't even sure it was an electric shock or just something weird that just happened to my elbow.

So I went ahead and touched the cable again, this time on the metal part. The shock was really painful this time and got me tingling :(

So I decided to unplug the cable and not use it again.

But I would like to find out if that is a problem with the cable, the USB port, or the laptop (in a way I don't get hurt again, of course)

Comment: Let me guess: Was the laptop plugged into its mains charger (with the mains power switched on and therefore the laptop was charging) at the time of this event?

Comment: Yes, it was charging

Comment: If you really are getting an electric shock then the most likely cause is a fault in the laptop mains charger. Repeat your experiment but with the mains charger disconnected - you shouldn't get a shock this time.

Comment: This would be a fault in your laptop charger or the wiring of the mains outlet it is plugged into.  **This is a potentially dangerous condition** and serious concern, but it is off topic and cannot be properly addressed *here* because it is not a question about electronic design but rather either about a faulty consumer product or faulty home wiring.

Comment: I would check the ground connection on the mains outlet (assuming the charger has a ground prong).  If it's not properly grounded you could get some leakage current from the Y-caps which would provide a tingle.  Otherwise you could have a faulty and unsafe charger, so be careful.  Unfortunately this IS off-topic for this site.

Comment: @SteveG As I said, I don't want to get hurt again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF the shock was mild the most probable cause is that the power supply is intended to have an earth connection (3rd pin) but does not have one, and has two "Y" filter capacitors on it's input side from each AC input line to its input ground lead. This causes the disconnected ground to float at Vinput_AC/2 at an impedance of about Zcap/2. If the input ground is connected to Vout_negative (as happens) then the voltage is enough to cause an unpleasant sensation to a grounded user who touches it.

Measuring from Vout_negative to mains ground should return a voltage of V_mains/2 or less (as the meter MAY slightly load the voltage.

The "solution" is to ground the ground lead on the power supply or the Vout_negative connection. Worst case this may cause operational issues, but shouldn't.

Worst case operationally is that

- connecting this power supply to equipment, OR
- connecting equipment connected to this power supply to other equipment,

MAY cause damage or destruction of some of the equipment.
Ask me how I know :-(. (Long ago).

Answer (score 1):

The shock could have been an electro-static discharge. If you want to find out if the laptop is safe or not, get a multimeter and probe from one of the grounding points on the outside of the laptop to AC mains/earth ground. (Usually the shields of ports are grounded).

Turn the meter on AC mode to measure RMS, then turn it on DC mode. In both modes the voltage should be low.
I would expect the voltage to be lower than 1V. If the voltage from earth ground to the laptop is more than 5ish volts then there could be a problem. If it's in the 10's of volts range, then there definitely is a problem and your laptop is probably unsafe.

If there is a low voltage (1V-10V) present, determining the impedance (how much current the laptop is leaking) of the voltage source is the next step. Turn the meter on to current mode, measure from AC mains ground again to a grounding point on the laptop, this time using a 100kΩ resistor in series (to be safe for starters). The current should be lower than 1mA for both AC and DC (and if your meter is good enough, in the uA range). Then use a 10kΩ, 1kΩ, 100Ω slowly working your way up to 10Ω. In each case the current should be low. If the laptop is sourcing more than 1mA, then there is a problem.

In this way you can check to see if the laptop is safe without touching it, make sure you don't touch the leads either or the resistor while testing.

Answer (score 0):

If the wall adapter was plugged in to the laptop, this is likely the source of the shock. Confirm this by unplugging it and touching the USB cable. The shock should go away.

For an isolated-secondary supply like a wall charger, a small amount of leakage is allowed (3mA) - low enough such that it is just detectable by touch, but not so much that it can harm you. If it’s actually painful the adapter could be defective and should be replaced.